# 2d drawings drag and zoom very slowly in Autodesk Forge viewer. How to increase performance?

Tags: performance, autodesk-viewer

Starting with the Digital Twin framework (https://forge-digital-twin.autodesk.io/#), but using a 2d file instead, the zoom performance is very laggy. The total geometry size is 82 MB, but I have the same performance when I hide most layers and only a small layer of polygons is visible. I have removed several features from the original digital twin as well.

I don't know how to make the display more responsive.

Yes, someone is going to say I have not provided enough detail for them to help. Probably true. Consider this a starting point then.

Comment: It will be more helpful to have a reproducible demo drawing to test. While may I firstly know: does this problem occur if loading the drawing in a simpler web skeleton? e.g. one viewer only, instead of in forge-digital-twins. This would help a bit to narrow down the issue. If you do not want to share drawing or related info, please feel free to email the case to forge.help@autodesk.com

Comment: Good news. The problem is related to how I need to interact with the file, which I am hoping goes away in production mode. Uploading the dwg file to Fusion Team provides zippy performance, even using a VPN on my local machine. However, I need the VPN to access the sandboxed server, and I must use remote desktop to do that. Logging into Fusion Team on the server's browser (using Remote Desktop), gives identical lag. I do not think this is related to data transfer, as in mouse click/screen sync/refresh rate, because 3D models also render the parts very slow. Server graphics card?